# how to update mysql table Which already exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with hundreds of tables I bring just an example
this is my database That's how it looks :
my table call stuff
That is how the table looks

```
id name

1  001

2  002

3  003
```

Now I have an update that I just want to update After table 3 
Because a different computer is created not the server

```
INSERT INTO `stuff` VALUES (1, '004');
INSERT INTO `stuff` VALUES (2, '005');
```

I currently have 2 backups

stuff1.sql AND stuff2.sql

My question is with a possible update table without starting to number it in order

I could have done it like this :

```
INSERT INTO `stuff` VALUES (1, '001');
INSERT INTO `stuff` VALUES (2, '002');
INSERT INTO `stuff` VALUES (3, '003');
INSERT INTO `stuff` VALUES (4, '004');
INSERT INTO `stuff` VALUES (5, '005');
```

But what do you do when there are many tables?

Comment: *possible update table without starting to number it in order* not sure what exactly are you asking

Comment: How do I update a table How do I add the update? Table already exists

Comment: so what's the problem. if table already exists ?

Comment: If I try to update I get 1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Please add the output of `show create table stuff;` to your question.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `stuff` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use id as auto increment and do this

```
INSERT INTO `stuff` (`name`) VALUES ('001');
```

and now it insert row with next id.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

try to write this in 'DDL' before insert the data :

[column_name] Integer- primary key - autoincremen ,